# Missing +/- setting for VM option 'UseSplitVerifier'

Tags: java, jvm, emma

I am running the emma code coverage tool in my system by using the below command,

```
D:\DeadLockDetection\DDinDOS>java -XX:UseSplitVerifier -cp emma.jar emmarun -jar process-3-1.0.jar
```

The below error is comming on running the above command,

```
Missing +/- setting for VM option 'UseSplitVerifier'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Error is clear. You [must use](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) 
`java -XX:+UseSplitVerifier` or `java -XX:-UseSplitVerifier`

Edit: UseSplitVerifier is boolean option for Oracle's JVM. The `-` or `+` after the `:`. Minus disabled the option, Plus enables the option.

From the above link...

> Boolean options are turned on with -XX:+ and turned off with
>   -XX:-. Numeric options are set with -XX:=. Numbers can include 'm' or 'M' for megabytes, 'k' or 'K' for
>   kilobytes, and 'g' or 'G' for gigabytes (for example, 32k is the same
>   as 32768). String options are set with -XX:=, are
>   usually used to specify a file, a path, or a list of commands

Comment: Glad to help. No need to say thanks in SO.  Here at SO we upvote to appreciate(no, I am  not soliciting an upvote here. )

Comment: @Jayan, can you please also explain the usage of "+" and "-" here? I can't find any references for the same.